# Difference between Window and DOMWindow?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, backwards-compatibility

I'm working on a project for a really old webkit browser. I'm having tons of issues, and when I was debugging it using https://jsconsole.com I noticed that `console.log(window);` was returning different things. On the latest version of Chromium it returned `[object Window]` but on the old browser it returned `[object DOMWindow]`. Could this be a cause of my problems, or is this just an older version?

FYI, the user-agent returns `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; ; U; Linux armv7l; en-us) AppleWebKit/534.26+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/534.26+`

Comment: It's an implementation detail.  What are your problems?

Comment: `DOMWindow` is probably a subtype of `Window`, and it's valid to use a subtype anywhere the parent type is required. That's how type hierarchies work.